# Find lines starting with a number in range

Tags: python, csv

I've got data that looks like this

```
18  -3.248418   0.326600    1.096954    0.536294    -0.192884   0.071945    1.000000    
19  -3.498030   0.396155    1.101706    0.628693    -0.231044   0.071432    1.000000    
20  -3.827249   0.453596    1.135211    0.723203    -0.312638   0.077363    1.000000    
21  -4.178354   0.558543    1.094458    0.813547    -0.383654   0.059875    1.000000    
22  -4.520537   0.712326    1.025310    0.918873    -0.494836   0.040987    1.000000    
23  -4.898419   0.874629    0.872843    1.072562    -0.581968   0.022534    1.000000    
24  -5.178654   0.986722    0.762628    1.235058    -0.656758   0.022830    1.000000    
25  -5.497410   1.139729    0.608902    1.419559    -0.751435   0.012771    1.000000    
26  -5.685015   1.279948    0.377152    1.601394    -0.869300   0.016318    1.000000    
27  -6.058228   1.424318    0.105117    1.845609    -1.011224   0.009828    1.000000    
28  -6.426589   1.548294    -0.172656   2.048423    -1.112269   0.015640    1.000000    
29  -6.786007   1.633135    -0.527714   2.268596    -1.259513   0.002945    1.000000
```

How do I get only lines starting with a number in a specific range?

I want to do something like `if line.startswith("20-25"):` but that obviously doesn't work.
I need to do this for multiple files with different ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the condition `20 <= num <= 25`, where `num` is an integer.

```
import csv
with open('filename') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
       if  20 <= int(row[0]) <= 25:
            #Do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if int(line[:2]) in range(20, 26):
```

If your numbers may vary in length (i.e. not always two characters), you will need to [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the line:

```
if int(line.split(" ", 1)[0]) in range(20, 26):
```

Or, given that you will probably need to process the rest of the line as floats under some circumstances:

```
index, data = line.split(" ", 1)
if int(index) in range(20, 26):
    data = map(float, data.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're looking for one range, you can stop reading the file once you've hit the end of that range. And because your columns are separated by whitespace, `str.split()` should do the trick:

```
def process_file(filename, range_low, range_high):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            row = line.split()
            i = int(row[0])
            if i < range_low:
                continue
            if i > range_high:
                break
            data = [float(x) for x in row[1:]]
            # ...
```